# login screen before splitview ipad

Tags: ipad

I need to present a login Viewcontroller after adding the spliviewController as rootviewcontroller

```
MasterVC *masterViewController = [[[MasterVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"MasterVC" bundle:nil] autorelease];
UINavigationController *masterNavigationController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:masterViewController] autorelease] ;
masterNavigationController.navigationBar.barStyle=UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;
masterNavigationController.delegate=masterViewController;

Home *detailViewController = [[[Home alloc] initWithNibName:@"home" bundle:nil] autorelease];
UINavigationController *detailNavigationController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:detailViewController] autorelease];
detailNavigationController.navigationBar.barStyle=UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;

self.splitViewController = [[[UISplitViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
self.splitViewController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:masterNavigationController, detailNavigationController, nil];


 self.window.rootViewController=self.splitViewController;
    LoginVC *modalLoginView = [[[LoginVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoginVC" bundle:nil] autorelease];
[modalLoginView setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFullScreen];
[self.splitViewController presentModalViewController:modalLoginView animated:NO];

[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
```

But the login View is not being shown.
Kindly help.thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try presenting the modal view in either your master or detail view's viewDidAppear event.
Apparently the appDelegate is too soon to be trying to do UI presentation stuff since there is no interface yet.

You'll also need to add your splitViewController's view to your window as a subview.

```
[self.window addSubView:self.spliViewController.view];
```